# Added a few lines of code and now query is taking 5x as long to run. Executions plans are almost identical

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that has been in production a long time and takes an average of 4 seconds to run. I added the code below which is a declaration of a table and then an insert into that table. then the select query joins to that and returns 1 field from it in the select statement. Now the query takes up to 25 seconds to run.

```
DECLARE @tmpStageLoc TABLE
        (
          LP VARCHAR(20) ,
          stgloc VARCHAR(20)
        )

    INSERT  INTO @tmpStageLoc
            EXEC dbo.spGetStageLoc @ActLP = @LP;

--Try to get data from DW tables first. 
    INSERT  INTO [COMMON_INFORMATION].[dbo].[ProcTmpData]
            ( SPID ,
              DataSetName ,
              IntValue1 ,                      --JRB004
              ChValue1 ,                       --JRB001
              String1 ,
              InsDate
            )
            SELECT DISTINCT
                    @@SPID ,
                    @datasetname ,
                    ls.ToDC ,
                    col.Cust_No                        --JRB001
                    ,
                    REPLACE(@LOADNUM, ' ', '') + --JRB007
                    '~' + 'N/A'
                    + --JRB005 Wave number no longer printed on label
                    '~' + CASE WHEN la.stage_loc IS NULL THEN ''
                               ELSE la.stage_loc + '-' + ISNULL(la.misc_info,
                                                              '')
                          END + '~' + fa.OrderControlNo + '~' + col.Cust_No
                    + '~' + SUBSTRING(cst.name, 1, 20) + '~'
                    + SUBSTRING(cst.name, 21, 5) + '~' + LEFT(cst.address1
                                                              + ', '
                                                              + CASE
                                                              WHEN cst.address2 IS NULL
                                                              THEN ''
                                                              ELSE ( cst.address2
                                                              + ', ' )
                                                              END + cst.city
                                                              + ', '
                                                              + cst.state, 45)
                    + '~' + ls.StopNO + '~' + ls.LoadNo + '~' + e.first_name
                    + ' ' + e.last_name + --JRB009
                    '~' + --JRB009
    CASE WHEN cst.plt_usage IS NULL      --JRB009
              THEN ''                          --JRB009
         ELSE                                 --JRB009
              '# ' + LEFT(cst.plt_usage, 20)        --JRB009
    END + '~' + ISNULL(STG.STGLOC, '') + '~'                               --JRB009
                    ,
                    @RUNDTE
            FROM    dbo.tblFactAction AS fa
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMON_INFORMATION.dbo.LoadStop AS ls ON LEFT(fa.OrderControlNo,
                                                              8) = ls.ExtOrderNo
                                                              AND ls.LatestLoadFlg = 1      --JRB008
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RP_LaneAssign AS la ON ls.LoadNo = la.carrier_move_id
                                                              OR ls.ExtOrderNo = la.order_num
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Cust_Order_Lookup AS col ON fa.OrderControlNo = col.Order_Control_no
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMON_INFORMATION.dbo.Partners AS cst ON col.Cust_No = cst.partner_shipto
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMON_INFORMATION.dbo.Employee AS e ON fa.EmployeeID = CAST(e.emp_no AS VARCHAR(40))
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @tmpStageLoc STG ON fa.actlp = STG.LP
            WHERE   fa.ActLP = @LOADNUM
                    AND fa.AssignTypeID IN ( 'PB01', 'PF01' )
```

I have looked at the execution plans in SQL Sentry Plan Explorer and they look almost identical. I am using the free version of the software. I am at a loss at why the query takes so long to run. just an FYI when I execute the stored procedure that is being called it runs instantly.

Any ideas on how I can figure out why the query now runs for so long?

Comment: Have you updated statistics?

Comment: Try to add the actual plans on PasteBin (or somewhere) as XMLs, and people will be able to create the plans for themselves and see the real difference. Way easier than inspecting code.

Comment: Slow Plan -   http://pastebin.com/pPgMR7t5 
Fast Plan -   http://pastebin.com/04twkdX6

Comment: What lines did you add?

Comment: I updated the statistics... still no luck.

Comment: Here is the same query passed 2 different values but one takes much much longer than the other. 40sec vs 1 sec.

Here are the execution plans.

any ideas? 

http://snipt.org/BgHj0 - Fast Version
http://snipt.org/BgIa9 - Slow Version

in the previous post the only code I added was the declaration of the @tmpstagloc table and then insert into it... then in the select under that it joins to it and selects 1 field from it. In some cases it's really fast in some cases it's really slow.

Comment: your execution plans are incomplete, so it is impossible to download and evaluate them. Modify your question to include the entire code that runs fast and than below add the additional code that makes it slow. and re-post execution plans.